# Inconsistent Behavior with SearchParams: Sending Object through Params Fails on Certain Instances

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I tried my best to recreate the problem here:

on my index I have this:

```
        <Section section="cat1" />
        <Section section="cat2" />
        <Section section="cat3" />
```

The section component essentially fetches the category I input, so in this instance cat1,2 and 3 will be fetched.

Section.tsx (this is shortened/pseudo)

```
const Section = (props) => {

useEffect(() => {

    let cat = fetch(props.cat)
    //cat logs perfectly, and I get the array of objects I want
})

}
then in my tsx, I just map over the cat

{cat?.map((item, index) => (

 <CatCard cat={item}/>
);         )}
```

The catCard is just a card that displays a specific object within the array, so imagine cat1 being an array of objects , and each Item gets a catCard.

The CatCard has a touchableOpacity, that when I click, I'm sent to the view page to view that specific product in more details

```
const CatCard = ({ cat}: This is an object) => {

// cat looks something like this: 

{category:"holiday", price:2, sale:false,....}

  return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.5}
        onPress={() => {
          console.log("first");
          router.navigate({
            pathname: `/product/view`,
            params: { product: JSON.stringify(cat) },
          });
        }}
        className="rounded-lg  h-[70%]"
      />

}
```

In my TouchableOpacity, on the onPress function, I can log the "cat" object every time, and it logs fine. However, for some very weird reason, when I send it through the params, some specific products go through while others don't. Mind you, they're all identical. For troubleshooting, I removed the router.navigate and just logged out the category every time the button is clicked. The category logs fine, but when I navigate, in some instances (i.e., some specific products), I'm able to send over the products in my params, while on other products, I just get an empty object.